# Deezer JavaScript SDK player login fails on redirect page while login

Tags: javascript, oauth, cross-domain, deezer

I'm trying to setup Deezer SDK in my web app. I call `DZ.login` in this way:

```
window.DZ.init({
  appId: process.env.DEEZER_APP_ID,
  channelUrl: 'http://127.0.0.1:3000/deezer-channel',
  player: {
    onload: function () {
      console.log('dz loaded');

      window.DZ.login((res) => {
        console.log(res);
      });
    }
  }
});
```

But then I have I have following error on my **redirect page**:

[image]

Debugging shows that Deezer script on redirect page tries to access DZ object in some other iframe's global object. And it throws this error.

What am I doing wrong?

**This question is not related to CORS rules itself. It is related to Deezer SDK OAuth!**

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It appeared my dev environment ran on `localhost:3000`. So redirect page that was opened at `127.0.0.1:3000` treated it as cross-domain resource.

Comment: Even more. `DZ.init` fails when devtools are open.